# The answer is not clear c++

Tags: c++

Here is a test question:

Consider the following code:

```
class A {
    typedef int I; // private member
    I f();
    friend I g(I);
    static I x;
};
```

Which of the following are valid:

```
a. A::I A::f() { return 0; }
b. A::I g(A::I p = A::x);
c. A::I g(A::I p) { return 0; }
d. A::I A::x = 0;
```

Answer to this question is considered correct only the first version (a.), but why? All them are valid in my opinion. Even tested all they compile successfully. Why only the first answer is correct?

Comment: It would be difficult to claim that `typedef int I;` is a member; it is a private type, but not really a member.  However, that hardly affects the answer to your question, or the question inside your question.

Comment: @Deduplicator OK; the standard says types are members — I won't argue against the standard and I'll try to update my terminology.  What I (used to) think of as members are, apparently, data members.  Oh well…

Comment: Perhaps b & c are considered incorrect (though that is not the same as invalid) because since A::I is private you could never call g(), except from a private method such as f(). Can't think of a possible reason d could be considered wrong.

Comment: @Narek: good thing you questioned the test itself. Scientific doubt. +1

Comment: How do you know that only a) is correct? The question says "are", indicating that several answers are at least possible to give. Did you try?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Whoever wrote the original answer to the test is wrong.

- This example comes (exactly) from the **C++ standard itself**, section § 11/7, [class.access], and has been copied by the one who wrote the "test"

The example goes even further in the standard, with templates (I'll omit them here):

```
      class A {
          typedef int I;      // private member
          I f();
          friend I g(I);
          static I x;
      };

      A::I A::f() { return 0; }
      A::I g(A::I p = A::x);
      A::I g(A::I p) { return 0; }
      A::I A::x = 0;
```

- Quoting the standard for the explanation:

> Here, all the uses of `A::I` are well-formed because `A::f` and  `A::x`  are
>   members  of  class  A and g is a friend of class A.  This implies, for
>   example, that access checking  on  the  first  use  of  `A::I`  must  be
>   deferred until it is determined that this use of `A::I` is as the return
>   type of a member of class A.  ]

- [It compiles with both gcc and clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/29044ea9180c723e)

Comment: Can I compile the code online with the link you have provided?

Answer (score 4):

They are all valid C++.

Here is the exact code, it is an example from the standard itself:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/open/n2356/access.html

This is how I parse them:

```
a. A::I A::f() { return 0; } // defines A::f() which was previously prototyped

b. A::I g(A::I p = A::x);    // declares prototype g(A::I), but doesn't define it

c. A::I g(A::I p) { return 0; } // defines g(A::I)

d. A::I A::x = 0; // defines static storage for A::x which was previously declared in A
```

These all compile, both individually, and collectively.

Comment: This is an oDesk C++ test question. You can search "typedef int I; // private member" in Google, and in each site Google find the string you see correct answer is marked only the first answer. How this could be?

Comment: One more reason to avoid oDesk.

Comment: What was the other reason?